# How to get the contents of a UIView even if it is being rendered with gl or metal

Tags: ios, uiview, opengl-es

I would like to get the contents of a UIView.  The UIView is offscreen and another library is rendering content to the view.  I believe the library is actually rendering to an underlying GL or metal surface.

When I try renderincontext i only get the UI elements within the view (like sliders, buttons etc).  I dont get the imagery behind.

Is there a way to get the content that is being sent to GL or metal?

And yes - this is a terrible hacky thing that I am trying to do and hopefully it is a short term hack.

Comment: Try: https://pastebin.com/bZ23MBZf

Comment: And that was it.  drawViewHierarchyInRect works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that [`snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotviewafterscreenupdates) should do the trick.

[Here's an article introducing it](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-7-taking-snapshots-of-uiviews).

This article also discusses how to render the view to an image, which is what @Brandon's comment points out.

Comment: Yeah - I saw snapshoviewafterscreenupdates before but it has this blurb "If the current view is not yet rendered, perhaps because it is not yet onscreen, the snapshot view has no visible content." Also the article you linked has this "Because the snapshot methods create versions which respect the appearance of the views on-screen, they are only able to snapshot views which are on-screen. This means it’s not possible to use these methods to create snapshots of views which you want to animate into view – an alternative approach must be used."

Comment: @PineappleJoe I'm not sure if this helps, but could you put the view on screen and obscure it with another view?

Comment: Interesting point.  I'll try that after I try drawViewHierarchyInRect.

Comment: @PineappleJoe Good luck, these things are tricky. Let me know how things go.